# php array foreach loop data manipulation

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a script which gets data from MongoDB in the form of an array and show the results. The array has many records. The sample array is as follows:

```
array(2) {   ["mac"]=> string(17) "2c:33:7a:10:f8:39" int(1478199995) ["duration"]=> int(5) }

array(2) {   ["mac"]=> string(17) "38:0b:40:ad:03:53" int(1478203338) ["duration"]=> int(3) }

array(2) {   ["mac"]=> string(17) "38:0b:40:ad:03:53" int(1478201111) ["duration"]=> int(7) }

array(2) {   ["mac"]=> string(17) "2c:33:7a:10:f8:39" int(1478206709) ["duration"]=> int(7) }

array(2) {   ["mac"]=> string(17) "38:0b:40:ad:03:53" int(1478202821) ["duration"]=> int(6) }

array(2) {   ["mac"]=> string(17) "2c:33:7a:10:f8:39" int(1478202366) ["duration"]=> int(4) }

array(2) {   ["mac"]=> string(17) "38:0b:40:ad:03:53" int(1478205023) ["duration"]=> int(2) }
```

I am showing record with respect mac address like in above array mac address "2c:33:7a:10:f8:39" has three records and "38:0b:40:ad:03:53" has four, so i will add duration of each record and show on browser like this

```
2c:33:7a:10:f8:39          16sec
38:0b:40:ad:03:53          18sec
```

I am doing this by following logic which i think is too slow for 5000 to 6000 records.

I first get the mac address in an array and remove duplication and then run a for loop on that array and add all duration for specific mac my code is as below.

```
<?php
 foreach ($cursor as $document) {
 array_push($arr,$document["mac"]);
 }
 $arr=array_unique($arr);
 $duration=0;

for($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++){

 foreach ($cursor as $document) {

if($document["mac"]==$arr[$i])
 {

 $duration+=$document['assoc_time'];

 }

 echo $arr[$i]."      ".$duration;
  }

?>
```

How i can make this process fast and how to perform this task in only one foreach loop.

Comment: You might want to check out [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to see how you can make your code better. As a start, you can avoid calculating the `count()` of `$arr` on every iteration by storing that value before you begin looping: `$arrayCount = count($arr);`

Answer (score 0):

You should let mongodb do the summing. As your mdb query is missing, see https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/